# Can anyone give me some pointers for using SVM for user recognition using keystroke timing?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am trying to perform user identification using keystroke dynamics. The data consists of the timing of individual keystrokes. I am using an SVM for binary classification. How can I train this for multiple users?
i have times of dynamic keyword, very times of users, example “hello” h->16seg, e->10, l->30, o->20, therefore, i not have class(1pos, -1neg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVMs are a binary classifier. However, SVMs do give you a confidence score (a function of distance from the separating hyperplane). So, you can use this information in one of two popular ways to convert a binary classifier into a multiclass classifier. These two ways are [One-vs-All and One-vs-One](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91091/one-vs-all-and-one-vs-one-in-svm).

See [this article](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/multiclass-svms-1.html) on how to use SVMs in a multiclass setting.

For example, in the One vs. All setting, for each class you separate the training data into samples that belong to that class and samples that belong to any other class. Then you fit an SVM on that data. At the end of the day you have k classifiers if you have k classes. Then you run your test data through all k classifiers and return the class with the highest probability (confidence score).

Comment: i can use a classifier general? Any code for implementation?